# How to get rows with the max value by using Python?

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have R code to use data table to merger the rows with same FirstName and LastName but selecting the max value for specified columns(e.g. Score1, Score2, Score3). The input/output is as follows:

**Input:**

```
FirstName LastName Score1 Score2 Score3
fn1       ln1      41      88     50
fn1       ln1      72      66     77
fn1       ln1      69      72     90
fn2       ln2      80      81     73
fn2       ln2      59      91     66
fn3       ln3      75      80     66
```

**Output:**

```
FirstName LastName Score1 Score2 Score3
fn1       ln1      72      88     90
fn2       ln2      80      91     73
fn3       ln3      75      80     66
```

Now I want to migrate the R program to Spark. How can I do this by using Python?

Comment: How is your input in python? Is it a dictionary of lists or a json? Or is it a simple text file with rows?

Comment: Hi be_good_do_good, It is a CSV file with rows.

Comment: I am not a python expert, but I have been playing with pandas for a while and can at least give you some clues. Pandas is the module to use for sure. Then I recommend using groupby (although I have no experience with it, so not sure about the syntax). Once grouped, you can find the maximum values of each of the Score columns for each group. So, first `import pandas as pd`, then load your datafile into a dataframe (call it whatever you want, examples call it df): `df = pd.read_csv(**your file here**)` and then search StackOverflow and pandas documentation for details about groupby operations.

Comment: Thanks durbachit. Your direction is correct! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by durbachit, you'll want to use pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(**your file here**)
max_df = df.groupby(by=['FirstName','LastName']).max()
```

And max_df will be your desired output. [Docs for pandas groupby.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is exactly what I want!

Comment: minute faster to provide pandas solution, hence upvoting it :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way to do it with in-built packages of python:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

newdata = OrderedDict()
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as testr:
    testreader = csv.reader(testr)
    for row in testreader:
        name = row[0]+ '-' + row[1]
        if name in newdata:
            newdata[name] = [max(existdata, readdata) for existdata, readdata in zip(newdata[name], row[2:])]
        else:
            newdata[name] = row[2:]

    with open('newdata.csv', 'wb') as testw:
        testwriter = csv.writer(testw)
        for name, data in newdata.iteritems():
            testwriter.writerow(name.split('-') + data)
```

Best way is to do it is with Pandas, will post in a while.

## EDIT:

Here is the pandas code:

```
import pandas
readfile = pandas.read_csv('test.csv') # assuming your CSV is same directory as program
print readfile
```

[image: actual data]

```
max_readfile = readfile.groupby(['FirstName', 'LastName']).max()
print max_readfile
```

output:

[image: pandas output]

** @user2241910 quickly posted the pandas solution :)

Comment: Python Pandas are very powerful, upvoting your good question!! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas
rows = pandas.read_csv('rows.csv', delim_whitespace=True)
rows.groupby(['FirstName', 'LastName']).max()
```